# DataReader exception : Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed

Tags: c#, datareader

Why am I getting an datareader exception: **Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed.** When I stepped through using the debugger the program crash on            while (dbReader.Read()). dbReader is wrapped around a using statement so I don't understand how the reader is closed.

```
 using (OleDbDataReader dbReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader())
 {
    if (dbReader.HasRows)
    {
       dataTable.Load(dbReader);

       while (dbReader.Read())
       {
          //Processing
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Not sure but didn't `dataTable.Load()` already read all the data?

Comment: I want to load the data into the datatable but also perform business logic for each row

Answer (score 0):

A reader can only be consumed once. If you used the reader to populate a `DataTable` : that's it - the data is gone. It is basically a sequence over a socket - it isn't repeatable.

So: run your business logic on the data you've already loaded.

Answer (score 0):

As [Marc Gravell♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) already pointed out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48288899/5893316) you only can read once.

---

But answering your comment:

> I want to load the data into the datatable but also perform business logic for each row

You can create your `DataTable` manually by iterating over all received fields like:

```
var dataTable = new DataTable(tableName);

for (int field = 0; field < dataReader.FieldCount; field++)
{
    var column = new DataColumn(dataReader.GetName(field), dataReader.GetFieldType(field));
    dataTable.Columns.Add(column);
}
```

and after that, you can start reading the data one row after the other and filling your `DataTable` rows like:

```
while ( dataReader.Read() )
{
    var dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();

    // Option 1
    for (int i = 0; i < dataReader.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        dataRow[i] = dataReader[i];
    }

    // or Option 2
    dataRow["col1"] = dataReader["col1"];
    dataRow["col2"] = dataReader["col2"];
    dataRow["col3"] = dataReader["col3"];

    // or something else
    // ...


    dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
}
```

---

*You can also find some examples at the [Docs - DataTable.Load-Examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.load(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2).*
*Or for a more detailed look see [DataAdapters and DataReaders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataadapters-and-datareaders).*